# I have installed socket.io in my windows 7 (64 bits) computer. I get an error of "No valid exports main found for socket.io". Any fixes?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nodejs-server

I am using a windows 7 (64 bit) computer. I have an issue using socket.io for some reason. I am using VS Code and I have attached an image of the error with the GitHub link to produce the error. In this project, I am creating my own version of ZOOM / Google Meet. Any fixes are recommended! Thank you in advance!!

[image]

[This is my project to reproduce the error](https://github.com/Adhithya777/Error-1-Stack-Overlfow)

Comment: Would you please post the node version you're using?

Comment: Have you installed socket.io ? Does the directory `./zoom_clone/node_modules/socket.io` exist? In the error it says `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` so it seems like it's not installed.

Comment: My node version is v13.6.0 (This is the last version of the node that can be installed in windows 7 64-bits), NPM v6.13.4. I have installed the socket.io module in `./zoom_clone/node_modules/socket.io`. The video I a, using for reference on Youtube: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvlyzDZDEq4`